# Best practice to integrate Apache Camel into Java EE 6 application

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel

I'm looking for some advice/opinion on the best way to integrate Apache Camel into Java EE 6 application (Weld, JSF, JPA, EJB). I would like to use camel to query periodically some http resource outside of the application, which would download and process a file. Shall I use EJB @Singleton keeping the Camel context in there, or are there better options/practice to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use EJB, you can use Java 6 @Resource annotation within managed beans to provide the CamelContext via its own dependency injection mechanism.